# How to backup a folder and it's subfolders to CD/DVD

Tags: windows, backup

If I've got a folder structure that I'd like to split so that it could be burned to multiple CDs or DVDs, what's the best tool out there to accomplish this?

The folders/files have to be natively accessible once the split is done (no compression or physical splitting that would require a later join), and the folder structure should still remain intact as it spaces discs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](http://www.windowsbbs.com/windows-vista/79532-how-copy-folder-files-exceed-one-dvd.html) on WindowsBBS.com:

> First some background, I use Genie Backup Manager to backup my data. When I submit a job, it tells me how many DVDs will be required to complete the job.

Which to me implies that [Genie Backup Manager](http://www.genie-soft.com/Home/Genie_Backup_Manager_Home/Default.aspx) can do what you want.

The Backup Media on the [Features page](http://www.genie-soft.com/Home/Genie_Backup_Manager_Home/Feature.aspx) states:

> Span across more than one location using multi-drive spanning,

Also it's a commercial product so may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my small utility will help you: [hardlink](http://code.google.com/p/hardlink/wiki/FAQ)

It splits folder to chunks using hardlinks to preserve diskspace, so it requires NTFS. So if one has this files structure:

```
Root/Source 1/Hog 1 1Gb
Root/Source 1/Hog 2 1Gb
Root/Source 1/Hog 3 1Gb
Root/Source 2/Hog 4 1Gb
```

after split by 2Gb get this:

```
DestFolder/Disk 1/Source 1/Hog 1 1Gb
DestFolder/Disk 1/Source 1/Hog 2 1Gb
DestFolder/Disk 2/Source 1/Hog 3 1Gb
DestFolder/Disk 2/Source 2/Hog 4 1Gb
```

i.e. copying all disk to one folder will restore original folder.